# Rails auto_complete plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, textfield

I'm using the auto_complete plugin and have a simple autocomplete textfield by writing this in my controller:

```
class PrivateMessagesController < ApplicationController
  auto_complete_for :role, :name
```

and this in my view:

```
<label for="recipient">To:</label>
    <%= text_field_with_auto_complete :role, :name %>
```

I want to improve the autocompletion now by:

- Enabling multiple autocomplete items to be inserted in a textfield, using comma as a tokenizer
- Putting in conditions. e.g. only showing the names of certain Roles that fit a certain criteria
- Having each autocomplete item displayed in a vertical list, rather than simply separated by a space.

Answer (score 1):

try [simple autocomplete rails plugin](http://github.com/grosser/simple_auto_complete) it add a bit more flexibility e.g.

```
autocomplete_for :post, :title do |items|
  items.map{|item| "#{item.title} -- #{item.id}"}.join("\n")
end
```

and its unobstrusive so you can add your own js to modify the displayed tems